# Attempting to calculate NN distance and getting type error

Tags: python

Programming newbie here, working on my assignment for my postgraduate degree. The main problem is that I have no previous programming or maths background so I am basically reinventing myself in the process.

While attempting to calculate NN distance for wine.csv, i am getting the "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: '_LocIndexer' and '_LocIndexer'" error.

Would anyone be willing to have a look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong? I have typed the code as accurately as I could from the lecture example, yet I can't seem to get it to work. The error shows in rows 5, 17 and 31

````
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def manhattan(instance1, instance2):   ROW 5
    manhattan_distance = np.sum(np.abs(instance1 - instance2))
    return manhattan_distance

def distance_matrix(data):
    matrix = np.zeros((len(data),len(data)))
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(i,len(data)):
            if i == j :
                manhattan_distance = 0
            else:
                instance1 = data.loc(i)
                instance2 = data.loc(j)
                manhattan_distance = manhattan(instance1, instance2) ROW 17
            matrix[i,j] = manhattan_distance
            matrix[j,i] = manhattan_distance
        return matrix

column_names=['class','Alcohol','Malic acid','Ash','Alcalinity of ash','Magnesium',
              'Total phenols','Flavanoids','Nonflavanoid phenols','Proanthocyanins',
              'Color intensity','Hue','Diluted wines','Proline']

wine = pd.read_csv("wine.csv", names = column_names)

wine_class = wine["class"]
del wine["class"]

distance_matrix_manhattan = distance_matrix(wine) ROW 31 ```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The phrase "I get an error" isn't helpful for others attempting to debug your code. Please paste the full and exact error message you get into your post. This is far more helpful. Also, providing a sample data set (just a few lines is all we need, but ensure that those few lines still cause the error).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).